Sequence of projections that alters a $2^d$ tuple of points to a hyperparallelepiped
Suppose we have a $2^d$ tuple $\{ x_i \}_{i=0}^{2^d-1}$ of points in some $\mathbb{R}^n$. I would like to shift the points of this tuple in some controlled way, so that the final $2^d$ tuple $\{ y_i \}_{i=0}^{2^d-1}$ is a hyperparallelepiped. Here, this would mean that there are vectors $v_0, \ldots, v_{d-1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
\begin{equation}
\forall j \in \{0, \ldots 2^d-1\} \quad y_j = y_0 + \sum_{i=0}^{d-1} \alpha_i v_i,
\end{equation}
where $\alpha_{d-1} \cdots \alpha_0$ is $j$ expressed in binary notation. Note that we can think of numbers in $\{0, \ldots, d-1\}$ as abstract "directions" in which we can move, i.e., if move from $x_i$ in the $j$th direction, we get to $x_{i+2^j}$.
The shifts should be realized by a finite sequence of projections $P_0, P_1, \ldots P_{d-1} \colon \mathbb{R}^{2^d} \to \mathbb{R}^{2^d}$ such that the $i$th projection has in its kernel all vectors corresponding to $(n-i+1)-$faces of a $d$-dimensional hypercube. By face, we mean the alternating sum of all vertices of the hypercube that can be reached by moving from a given point in some selected $(n-i+1)$ abstract dimensions. For example, the $2$-face starting at vertex $4,$ and corresponding to directions $1,2$, is represented by vector $(0,0,0,0,-1,1,1,-1)$. (The sign is positive if the number of $1$s in binary expansion of the vertex's index is even, and negative, if the weight is odd).
If $X$ is a $n$ by $2^d$ matrix in which the columns are the points from the original tuple $\{ x_i \}_{i=0}^{2^d-1}$, then the tuple we get after the $j$th projection is comprised of columns of $XP_j$. Also, since the tuple we get after each projection is "closer" to being a hyperparallelepiped, we want to have $P_aP_b = P_bP_a = P_b$ if $a < b$.
Specifying the kernel of projections does not specify them fully. We also need to specify the eigenvectors of projections that correspond to eigenvalue 1. (This is the "control" part of shifting). Here, I would like to select these vectors so that we can partition the shifted points into hypercubes whose faces can be expressed as linear combinations of faces of the original hypercube represented by tuple $\{ x_i \}_{i=0}^{2^d-1}$. (As, in, for example, we would take $4$ points from one tuple and $4$ from a new one, treat this $8$-tuple as a hypercube and we want this hypercube to satisfy the faces property).

I found such sequence of projections for $d=2$ and $d=3,$ but I haven't found a way to do so for all $d \in \mathbb{N}$. If there is a way to generate such sequence of projections for any $d$, I would like to learn it.
I'm also interested in whether any similar problem was previously studied and where I could find some sources on it.
